# conditional probability with joint pdf

Tags: probability, random-variables, density-function

So I got stuck at the following problem:
Theres a bivariate random variable with joint pdf $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{e^\frac{-(x^2+y^2)}{2\sigma}}{2\pi\sigma^2}$$  $$(-\infty\lt x,y\lt \infty)$$
I was asked to find $P(X,Y)$ while given$\quad$ $x^2+y^2\le a^2$.
 please help me ! How do I set up the boundaries for my integral when calculating the CDF???

Comment: $x^2+y^2\le a^2$ implies $y^2\leq a^2-x^2 \iff x\in[-\sqrt{(a^2-y^2),}\sqrt{(a^2-y^2)}]$, you can use these boundaries. Or, in case you are familiar with polar coordinates, you can also use these by doing a coordinates transformation, as the given inequality states the pair $(x,y)$ should be within a circle with radius $a$.

Comment: I am not very clear, do you need the PDF or the CDF? If it is the CDF, do you need it for $x^2+y^2\le a$ or what you need is the CDF of $(X,Y)|X^2+Y^2\le a$? The last one seems to be very messy, with a lot of cases,

Comment: What i need is to find the CDF of (X,Y)|X^2+Y^2<a. Why is this case so messy though? is it because you have to do some boundary transformations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean. Given *pdf* $f_{X,Y}$, *pdf* conditional on $x^2+y^2\leq a^2$ is $f_{X,Y|X^2+Y^2\leq a^2}=\frac{f_{X,Y}}{\mathbb{P}[X^2+Y^2\leq a^2]}$.

You mean how do you calculate $\mathbb{P}[X^2+Y^2\leq a^2]$? Just observe $x^2+y^2\leq a^2$ is a circle with center at $(0,0)$ and radius $a^2$. So you take $x\in[-a,a]$ and for each $x$ you take $y\in[-\sqrt{(a^2-x^2)},\sqrt{(a^2-x^2)}]$.